# Macro runs but no data is pasted

Tags: excel, vba

First off, I am extremely new to excel vba.  I have some code that works well in one workbook but doesn't work in the workbook I need it in.  When using <kbd>F8</kbd>, it skips over the portion of the code beginning with `If Cells(i, 4) = customername Then` through `End If`.

I have searched for several days trying to find an answer online.  When I run the macro, the screen flashes but the data disappears.  Here is the code I am trying to use, any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub CustomerReport()
    Dim datasheet As Worksheet
    Dim reportsheet As Worksheet
    Dim customername As String
    Dim finalrow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Set datasheet = Sheet3
    Set reportsheet = Sheet8
    customername = reportsheet.Range("D6").Value

    reportsheet.Range("C8:M500").ClearContents

    datasheet.Select
    finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 8 To finalrow
        If Cells(i, 4) = customername Then
            Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 13)).Copy
            reportsheet.Select
            Range("C200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
            datasheet.Select
            End If
    Next i
    reportsheet.Select

    Range("D6").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/10718179#10718179) will get you started. I believe if you avoid using select and fully qualify the objects then you will not face the issues :)

Comment: What I mean is, see how you used `reportsheet` in `reportsheet.Range("D6").Value` but forgot to do the same in `If Cells(i, 4) = customername Then` and other places? :)

Comment: Put a message box to get the value of finalrow after the row `finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`, what shows up?

Comment: @SiddharthRout - `If Cells(i, 4) = customername Then` is inherently referencing the `datasheet` worksheet.

Comment: Are you sure you want to `xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats`? Typically a report does not rely upon formulas for its numbers; especially so when data is copied from another worksheet.

Comment: @jeeped. True that. I am advising the user to fully qualify the cells to negate any possibility of the code not finding a match. BTW I just posted a bug in meta. You may want to see it [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297189/incorrect-information-portrayed-for-closed-quesitons)